# Android: Button animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-transitions

In my MainActivity I have a `FrameLayout` container for a `Fragment`.

One of the `Fragments` is a normal rectangular `Button` and the other one is a circular `Button` (both buttons have the same height).

When I click the `Button` I want the rectangular `Button` to transform into circular `Button` like this:

[image]

This is the code I currently have:

```
Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();
setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_trans));
setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.fade));
fragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_trans));
fragment.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.fade));

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.button_container, fragment)
        .addToBackStack("transaction")
        .addSharedElement(view, "button_transition")
        .commit();
```

The problem is when I click the button it transform into an elliptic shape and then to a circular button, but when I click the back button the animation is smooth.

So how to correct it to be like in the example above, or a sample close to that (I only need the button animation).

Comment: I solved this a long time ago, but it seems that I'm getting up votes on this, so if anyone is interested let me know in the comments, and I will publish the code of it.